# Reading name and grade values java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am currently trying to write a program for a homework program that will read in values in the form

"John Q. Woodcutter|75|82|2|0|15|57|55|56|10|25|48" wherein the first value is the students name and the other values are there various marks through out the term. The order that marks are in matters as the position determines what mark they are e.g. the first is their exam and the second is their midterm. I am having trouble actually reading in the data in a useful matter so any help would be great. Here is what I have

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class A1
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      float ex, mid, bonus, cheat, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, grade,A; 
      float Jb=0;
      String name, letGr;
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please input grades");
      scanner.useDelimiter("|");
      name = scanner.next();
      ex = scanner.nextFloat();
      mid = scanner.nextFloat();
      bonus = scanner.nextFloat();
      cheat = scanner.nextFloat();
      a1 = scanner.nextFloat();
      a2 = scanner.nextFloat();
      a3 = scanner.nextFloat();
      a4 = scanner.nextFloat();
      a5 = scanner.nextFloat();
      a6 = scanner.nextFloat();
      a7 = scanner.nextFloat();
```

The rest of the code is just a series of if statements to do the actual grade calculation. Also if I want the program to accept a text file from the command line with test cases and run until the end of file what would be the best way to do this since I am not actually opening the file with the program?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, but you could use the scanner just to read in each line then split the line by "|", that way you can have any number of grades on each line:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input grades");

String line = scanner.nextLine();

while ( line.length() > 0 ) // quit when user enters no data
{
  String[] data = line.split("|"); // store the data in an array
  name = data[0];
  // use a for-loop to iterate from index 1 to data.length to see all the grades
  ...
  line = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

If you want the scanner to read until EOF:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/file.txt"));
while ( scanner.hasNextLine() )
{
  String line = scanner.nextLine()
  ... // parsing code in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of doing it that way! If I want to use the values in the array in order to some calculations with the grades would I do something like 'ex = Float.parseFloat(data[1]);' or is there a better way to turn the array elements into floats (floats were specified to be used in the assignment)

Comment: Exactly. I'm sure there are other ways, but that's probably the simplest and the one I would do.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I run the program with "colin|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11" just to test I get a variety of runtime errors and they are for input string "c" does that mean that it is failing somewhere before it even finishes reading in the name? I am sorry for all the questions, I just really struggle with java and this is the only java assignment in this course, the rest is all in C

Comment: I'd need more detail than that. You mean you enter just "c" and you get a bunch of runtime errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String str ;
        while ((str = reader.readLine())!=null) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);

            float ex, mid, bonus, cheat, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, grade,A; 
            float Jb=0;
            String name, letGr;
            System.out.println("Please input grades");
            scanner.useDelimiter("|");
            name = scanner.next();
            ex = scanner.nextFloat();
            mid = scanner.nextFloat();
            bonus = scanner.nextFloat();
            cheat = scanner.nextFloat();
            a1 = scanner.nextFloat();
            a2 = scanner.nextFloat();
            a3 = scanner.nextFloat();
            a4 = scanner.nextFloat();
            a5 = scanner.nextFloat();
            a6 = scanner.nextFloat();
            a7 = scanner.nextFloat();
        }
    }
```